# Flex: how to disable user interaction with application during server call?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need a method to disable user interaction with the application for certain calls to a server for information. I've been using the following code to disable/enable the application before/after the server call. Basically, it gives the user a busy cursor and disables the application while the call is being processed on the server.

When the call from the server is submitted, I execute:

```
CursorManager.setBusyCursor(); 
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled=false;
```

When the call from the server returns, I execute:

```
CursorManager.removeBusyCursor(); 
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled=true;
```

This has the problem that the application color dims. Is there a way to prevent it from dimming? Alternatively, can I disable the mouse click and keyboard somehow? Or, what do other people do in this situation?

Comment: If it's a Spark app, you could create a custom skin for the `Application` class and remove the part that says: `alpha.disabled="0.5"`

Comment: Thanks RIAstar. You know, there is an `mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.alpha` setting, but if I set it to 1 it has no effect when the application is in a disabled state.

Comment: That's the `alpha` of the `Application` instance, not its skin. You could set `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.skin.alpha` but even then I guess that value will still be overridden when the skin's state changes. You'll have to set it after the skin's `currentStateChange` event, but that's starting to look kind of ugly.

Comment: Ugly perhaps, but much simpler than the alternatives. Could you submit some code using `currentStateChange` as an answer?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it'll work. That 's why I didn't post it as an answer. And as far as simplicity goes: I reckon the custom skin solution would be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
// in your method
const stage:Stage = mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage;
if (stage)
  stage.mouseChildren = false; // or true of course
```

Comment: Thanks, can this also disable the keyboard somehow?

Comment: Yes, it should. You could disable KeyBoard events in the capture phase by calling Event#preventDefault() and Event#stopPropagation().

Comment: What does `if (stage)` check for (that is, under what condition is it true or false)?

Comment: When FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is not added to the stage, but you'd invoke the method, you'd get a 1009 TypeError, since stage would  be null.

Comment: I'm getting an error using flex 4.6 when executing `stage.mouseEnabled=false`: `Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method.` According to the documentation, you're right that `stage.mouseEnabled` will also block keyboard inputs.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just remove that setting of the property and it should be working fine.

Comment: OK, it does disable the mouse! However, the mouse cursor gets pinned down to it's last location before the server call. Is there any way to allow the user to still move the mouse cursor (while disabling the other mouse functionality and keyboard)? Also, looks like the keyboard only gets disabled for `stage.mouseEnabled=false`. The keyboard remains active using `stage.mouseChildren=false`. Otherwise, it's perfect.

Comment: Yes, you could just disable click events in the capture phase as described with the KeyboardEvents.

Answer (score 1):

I have an AMFConnector class that makes all my calls. Every time that this class will make a call, it sets the cursor to Busy Mode and sets a boolean property to true (amf_busy). All my application is built to use that property to active/desactive buttons that makes calls/commands.
Your solution is faster and easier, but as you stated, it fades the whole screen and it's not very user-friendly. Now as the user sees that when he made an action, just the buttons fades, he's automatically aware that he now has to wait the server to come back with an answer, even though he doesn't understand client-server calls.

Edit:
As to disable mouse/keyboard, it's not very user-friendly either. You have to be careful with the user profile if you go with that solution. It is likely that the user will see that 'sometimes' the keyboard/mouse stops to work 'for apparently no reason' since he doesn't understand what's happening.

Edit II:
Since I don't know how BlazeDS works, I will use my own example and you might try to translate it.

This is how a simple call would look like:

```
//creating a object connection.
var gateway:NetConnection = new Netconnection();
//connect
gateway.connect(url_connection_here);
//Making a simple call
gateway.call("UserController/GetUser", new Responder(onResult, onfault));
```

This is what you would do:

Create a gateway to receive the calls:

```
[Bindable] public class AMFConnctor{
      private var instance:AMFConnector = new AMFConnector();

      public function getInstance():AMFConnector{
          return instance;
      }

      public function AMFConnector(){
          if(instance){
            throw new Error("Singleton class cannot be instanced. Use getInstance() method instead.");
          }
      }

      private var _amf_busy:Boolean = false;        
      public function get amf_busy():Boolean{
             return _amf_busy;
      }

      public function set amf_busy(value:Boolean):void{
             //If you are setting to true (yes, it's busy)
             if(value){
                CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
                _amf_busy = true;
             }else{
                _amf_busy = false;
                CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
             }
      }

      //Here I assume that everytime that I ask this class for the gateway
      //it's because I'm going to make a call, which means that I want the
      //rest of the application knows that AMF is currently busy.
      public function get Gateway():NetConnection{
           amf_busy = true;
           return this._gateway;
      }
}
```

If you have a gateway similarly like this, you can now easily configure your buttons:

```
<mx:Button id="btnSubmit1" label="Submit" click="action" icon="@Embed(source='images/ok.png')"  enabled="{!AMFConnector.getInstance().amf_busy}"/>
<mx:Button id="btnCancel1" label="Cancel" click="action" icon="@Embed(source='images/cancel.png')" enabled="{!AMFConnector.getInstance().amf_busy}"/>
```

Now, the only thing that you have to make sure is that inside your 'onResult' functions, the ones that will be called after the Server Side returns your call, you have to make sure to set the amf_busy property to Off (false) and that will automatically enable back all the buttons.

Comment: I'm also using BlazeDS for server calls. Can you describe more about "...sets a boolean property to true (amf_busy)"? What's the code look like and how does it effect the user?

Comment: If the mouse cursor is "busy" state, the user probably won't expect he/she can click on anything, so disabling the mouse/keyboard here shouldn't be confusing to the user.

Comment: That's true. Although I don't use the Gateway just to enable/disable buttons. For me, it's important to have a manager that can tells me if a call is being made or it's all over and I also use this to avoid multiple calls. For instance, in some screens, you have to make tons of calls to the server to get different kinds of data so the user can use it in a ComboBox, DataGrid and etc. The way I use the gateway allows me to accumulate all the calls I want to make in one single call, then he dispatch it to the server inside only one connection tunnel, saving bandwidth and making it faster.

Comment: Interesting. Does it prevent `Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions` errors (which I'm seeing; I assume it's from multiple simultaneous calls to the server)?

Comment: I never had that kind of error, so I wouldn't know. But it's not something exactly automatic. What I had was multiple calls to multiples PHP Classes and each call had to establish her own connection with the server. Since the calls didn't have a cronologic order, sometimes it happened that, for instance, **models entity** were loaded before **manufactors entity** and my DataGrid had to show them both and the handler would dispatch an error since one of the entities wasn't ready yet. What I did was to hold the calls inside the gateway and dispatch a single call to a CallController PHP Class

Comment: and this class would take the information of the 'calls that flex would do' and it would do itself. Bottonline, with this structure the server is making calls to itself based on information brought from 1 single flex call and then I return everything to flex in that call and the Gateway handle which result goes where.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me...

```
private var _lastFocusedElement:InteractiveObject;

private function set enabled(value:Boolean):void {
    value ? CursorManager.removeBusyCursor(): CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
    var stage:Stage = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage;
    if (stage) {
        stage.mouseChildren = value;
        stage.tabChildren = value;
        if (!value)
            _lastFocusedElement = stage.focus;
        stage.focus = value ? _lastFocusedElement : null;
    }
}
```

Regards, Vjeko

Comment: What about keyboard input with labeled fields?

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple soution:-

```
protected static function toggleScreenClick (value : Boolean) : void

    {

        if (value)
        {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("disabledOverlayAlpha", 0.5);
        }
        else
        {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("disabledOverlayAlpha", 0.0);
        }
        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled = value;
    }
```